# Automatic deleting of highly inactive questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This question is not a duplicate of [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) since it is only for questions with low score. This question asks for automatic deleting all the questions satisfying the criteria below and is neither relevant to the question score nor the answer score.

---

The question is highly inactive if:

1. The question is at least as old than 730 days.
2. The number of views of the question is less than or equal to (the age of question in days) times 0.2.
3. The question and all of their answers all have no votes (downvotes and upvotes) cast in the past 365 days.
4. The question has no new answers in the past 365 days.
5. The question has no more than 4 answers.
6. The question is not closed and is not locked to answering.
7. It is not on the meta site.
8. Last activity was more than 120 days ago.

I suggest the highly inactive questions will be automatically deleted by Community Bot every 30 days across all sites.

These questions can only be undeleted by moderators. It takes 3 votes to reopen, and all reopen votes are retracted if no reopen votes were cast in the last 365 days. The same moderator can again cast the reopen vote to the question if his/her last reopen vote to this question is retracted.

Highly inactive questions can have many upvotes but no downvotes.

One example to discuss is the following question in MathOverflow:

[Does automatic decomposition of varieties into irreducibles exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2459/does-automatic-decomposition-of-varieties-into-irreducibles-exist)

It has 141 (or 137) views, it is asked in 2009, the question is upvoted with only one time, in 2021, and the answer is upvoted two times, once per first two days after posting. However, it was not downvoted.

The questions which are marked as highly inactive and have either positive score or at least one answer with a positive score need to be reopened and locked for all but voting.

The law of viewing states:

The average number of all views to all questions on any sitebis proportional to `integral(t0,t,(U_l/q) dt)`, where t is the current time, t_0 the time the question is asked U_l is the total number of logged users in a site in a time t, and Q is the total number of questions on that site in a time t.

So to have the number of views to every question growing linearly, the number of logged users on any site needs to be proportional to the number of questions on that site.

The questions with many upvotes and/or highly upvoted answers may also be uninteresting but notable. These questions need to be undeleted and locked by moderator as permanent theoretical significance. The permanent theoretical significance questions' restrictions are same to the historical significance questions and obsolete questions except they can be upvoted/downvoted.

Comment: An I correct that there is no consideration for *existing* score under this proposed system, only votes within the past year?

Comment: hmm, You are aware we have a system for this right? https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions (formerly known as Roomba)

Comment: I reccommended to have a system for these questions too.

Comment: It is recommended that [feature-request] questions provide a justification for why the feature should be added. Why would it be useful to delete highly inactive questions?

Comment: You've described your request, but you've given *no information* as to **why** this should be done. What benefit would there be to deleting *huge* swaths of questions? On SO, this would delete *on the order of 5M questions* (just a rough estimate from [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+created%3A..2y+answers%3A..4+closed%3Ano+locked%3Ano+views%3A..146) and looking a bit at higher views counts for even older questions, which is just going to be a ballpark, but is probably low by a couple million).

Comment: @Sonic The OP is proposing to delete pages of inactive content even if the posts have high scores.

Comment: This post doesn't meet the guidance for [tag:feature-request], it either should be improved to provide a rational / justification / explanation of why this change should be done or it should be retagged as [tag:discussion] and improved its wording accordingly. It also lacks of research, as it doesn't make reference to previous simlar requests and to related features, there a no examples, etc., etc.

Comment: Please provide more information about this visualization law that you mentioned. It may not be, but to me it seems like a twisted use of the [empirical Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law), which deals with occurrences of specific words within a linguistic corpus. And I don't want to run the risk of giving an opinion on a subject that I don't know about.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There isn't consideration for the *existing score* to this question. Even if the question or some of its answers have a score of 101 or -51, say, and is old 1095 days, the question may or may not be highly inactive.

Comment: Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just opinions on the quality of the post, although votes can also reflect that. On feature requests, voting typically represents peoples' agreement for or against the feature request. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta should not be automatically considered to mean that there are problems with the post. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt to double-check that the post quality is good.

Comment: I'd also add that as an experienced user - I generally wouldn't suggest making *fundamental* changes to the system. One needs a *deep* understanding of the network and meta culture for posts on that to be successful

Comment: Also that's a lot of edits - it might be worth thinking about your question and ensuring its fully formed and *ready* rather than 'writing it live' and constantly bumping things up

Comment: This is requuired to balance the number of questions on any site. If this question isn't poorly written, it needs to be reopened and locked so that the voting is still allowed on this question.

Answer (score 13):

No, I'm strongly opposed to this. High quality, even mainstream questions and answers would be culled for no good reason at all. Lack of SEO to bring in views? Failure to expand the active voting populace of the site every year? What exactly *is* the purpose? Niche Q&A might as well be deleted on the spot.

Look at [What exactly is an editor?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/2126/34330). This question has a score of 18, with answers scoring 21 and 7, which is pretty high for that site (top 5% of questions on Writing). Like many other Q&As I looked at, voting abruptly stops after 2018. It's a broadly applicable question, but your system would have deleted it years ago. (For reasons unrelated to the site, participation was in free fall in 2019 and still hasn't recovered.)

To get a good idea of what old questions might be deleted if this were implemented, try searching for `created:..10y views:0..800 answers:..4` which will get you close to the criteria. I didn't search very much, but there's a lot I found that I wouldn't want to lose.

Our existing auto-deletion only deletes questions when they haven't been upvoted much or received even the most mediocre of answers (as defined by votes), so nothing much is lost. Your suggestion is on a whole new level and would lead to lots of valuable content being deleted.

Comment: `created:..10y` gets you questions which are > 10 years old. The proposal is to start deleting at > 2 years old. The views restriction does limit the number, but the views criteria isn't all *that* much of a restriction. Depending on the site on which the search is done, your current suggested search criteria will be low by a significant multiple, potentially more than an order of magnitude, as it has no information for questions > 2 years old, but < 10 years old.

Comment: These questions are probably marked as very uninteresting, so the suggestion is to be automatically deleted.

Comment: The questions needs to be asked more slowly and slowly overall and to be edited more often. The population on Earth will probably never reach 10^11 and certainly 10^12, so this is going to make sense.

Comment: @JovanRadenkovic I have no idea what you're talking about. Why do you think we need to delete "uninteresting questions"? Why would questions with dozens of votes even be uninteresting? What does this have to do with the global population? How does editing factor into this, when none of the criteria at all have to do with editing?

Comment: Because one person can't view 10000 answers per day. The number of questions in any site needs to be usually 2^24 or less.

Comment: @Laurel, The number of views to every question needs to grow at least linearly.

Comment: It is better for this question to be locked as permanent theoretical significance and therefore not to be automatically deleted by Community Bot.

Comment: Also, the questions with many upvotes have a large number of views.